# search in multiple columns with multiple keywords in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

suppose keyword search is samsung s21 ultra 64 gb

- samsung is brandName field
- s21 ultra is modelName field
- 64 gb is  size field

example search :

- s21 64 gb
- samsung s21
- iphone xr
- iphone
- iphone 13 max pro 512 gb
- 13 pro 256 gb

what can be query or approach

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this query in mongodb

```
db.collection.find({"brandName":"samsung", "modelName":"s21", " size":"64 gb" })
```

Comment: search can be anything 
ex:  s21 64 gb,
samsung s21,
iphone xr,
iphone,
iphone 13 max pro 512 gb, 
then above query will fail

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: empty result.no records found.